# ALTER TYPE ... ADD cannot run inside a transaction block - Entity Framework

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm getting an error when trying to run migrations to a PostGres database when I'm adding an enum. I'm using Dotnet5 and Entity Framework

ALTER TYPE ethnicity_enum ADD VALUE 'hi';
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 25001: ALTER TYPE ... ADD cannot run inside a transaction block

Here's the migration that is created:

```
 protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase()
            .Annotation("Npgsql:Enum:patient_ethnicity_enum", "afna,hi")
            .OldAnnotation("Npgsql:Enum:patient_ethnicity_enum", "afna");

    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase()
            .Annotation("Npgsql:Enum:patient_ethnicity_enum",
                "afna")
            .OldAnnotation("Npgsql:Enum:patient_ethnicity_enum",
                "afna,hi");
    }
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Don't start a transaction before you execute the statement.

Comment: How can you avoid that? It's done via the database update command as a part of ef?

Comment: Are you using Postgres version 11 or less?

Comment: I don't pretend to understand EF, but how about [Suppress transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.sql.migrationstatement.suppresstransaction?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)? I have also seen suggestions to use raw SQL to do the enum alter, though no actual code was provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following a comment from Adrian, I found you can do it this way.

```
  migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER TYPE patient_ethnicity_enum ADD VALUE 'hi'", true);
  migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase();
```

The "true" parameter is for suppressing the transaction.

This works but It's not ideal as rolling the migration back could potentially cause massive issues on live data.